# How can I write correctly in Serialport .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I'm writing a program that communicates with another one, through 2 virtual serial ports.
Everything looks good, except when I click on the Windows start button, and try to open other app. The program to which I'm sending data desynchronizes, and it is reading wrong bytes. I cannot change the other program, just my own. Has someone any idea what could cause this? I'm using C# in .Net Framework.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There is not sufficient information to help you solve your problem. You should start by showing an minimal example of the failing code. It would also help if you could describe what troubleshooting steps you have attempted so far. It would for example be very useful if you could confirm that the serial communication works in some other program to help isolate the problem.

Comment: I always advise people to read this before using the `SerialPort` class: https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: ^ A must read for anyone who has tried to serial port in C#

Comment: Make sure the settings for the serial port are correct (rate, number bits).  You may also have issues with Little/Big Endian.

Comment: So, I got the communication very well, but my problem is when I try to open another software on the computer, like PowerPoint or another. My software is reading, decoding the protocol, and writing back an information all the time, but when another process starts, the data that I sent, it is readed incorrectly. I've done a log to see if was my code that was writing incorrectly, but everyting looks fine. I am using the function Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count); , from System.IO.Ports.SerialPort .

Comment: This article may be helpful. [Serial Comms in C# for Beginners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners)

Comment: Thank you kunif. It is interesting. But to my problem, I think it don't help enough. =/

Comment: As others have commented, your question lacks information for others to understand, reproduce, and investigate the problem. Please refer to these help articles to improve your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to help you, specifically the code you wrote that is not working.  See: [ask].  Absent that, your question may get closed as [needing debugging details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397281).